# how to convert rfid tag data (askii) to string in JAVA

Tags: java, serial-port, raspberry-pi, rfid

I'm using the (id12 innovations) RFID read with a Raspberry Pi.
Using the PI4J java library and it's serial example, I'm able to read some data like (5002CF13C6) i'm not sure what this data is! it suppose to get this number (0002948115).

here's is my code:

```
// create an instance of the serial communications class
final Serial serial = SerialFactory.createInstance();

// create and register the serial data listener
serial.addListener(new SerialDataListener() {
@Override
public void dataReceived(SerialDataEvent event) {
    //-----------
    System.out.print("\n" + event.getData());
    //-----------
}

});

try {
    // open the default serial port provided on the GPIO header
    serial.open("/dev/ttyAMA0", 9600);

    // continuous loop to keep the program running until the user terminates the program
    for (;;) {
        try {

        } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            // wait 1 second before continuing
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Rfid.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

} catch (SerialPortException ex) {
    System.out.println("e: RFID setup failed : " + ex.getMessage());
}
```

what should i do to event.getData() in order to be able to read the real data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.getData()`, is returning to you exactly what the id12 chip is saying on the serial port.  The data is a 10 character string representation of a hexadecimal number, followed by a 2 character checksum.

The behavior is specified in the id12 datasheet, which can be quickly found on google, or here: http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Sensors/ID/ID-2LA,%20ID-12LA,%20ID-20LA(2013-4-10).pdf .  In the linked PDF, it is page 4.

If you would like some help parsing this data in java, please supply some actual read data, and the corresponding expected values belonging to that read data.

Comment: Hi, so the ID12 is sending me a HEX data which has to represent the decimal card number.
here's an example of my problem: if the card number (decimal) is 0002948115 then its HEX should be: 2CFC13. 
BUT when I swipe this card I got the following result: x5002CFC13C6 {this '2CFC13' is included in the result. the 'C6' is the checksum. now what about the 'x500'?? note that x here represent a very wired character appearing at the begging of the all the results}

Comment: Actually, the 002CFC13 is data.  This leaves us only with the x5 character to explain.  The specification says that the chip sends an STX control character (ASCII value: 2).  Perhaps this is the mystery character.  After the newline you should be able to find an ETX character as well.

Comment: Hey thank you so much, I have no idea how I did it but I removed 3 chars from the beginning and 5 chars from the end to get the '002CFC13' out of 'x5002CFC13C6'.
here's the code:
String serialHexOnly = serial.substring(3, serial.length() - 5);
I test it on more than 20 other cards and it works 100%